# Multiple differentiation of chain rule $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))$ computationally

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

The question was to find a simplified expression for
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))$$
I was working to find some types of recursion relationship
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(x))= \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}} (f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x))  $$
which was not some simple expression such as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} f^{n-k}(g(x)) \cdot g^{k}(x) $$

I'm thinking about to implement the solution computationally. It occurred that the sympy package was rather slow when $n$ was large(100-1000).

Is there any particular standard expression from computational mathematics for evaluating this types of expressions?

Comment: Are you familiar with the "Faà di Bruno's formula"? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: @G.Blaickner That might be it. I have seen some part of it (the Bell polynomials), but not really. From the recursion of the partial Bell polynomials, it's simplified to $O(n)$?

Comment: What functions $f$ and $g$ do you have? There are many [special case formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/9/) for the derivatives.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I'm doing bootstrap of the Dedekind eta function, $\partial_\tau \frac{1}{\eta(q(\tau))}$ so it's more like $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(g(h(x)))$. This can be resolved by applying the Faa Di Bruno's formula noted by G. Blaickener twice, but the computation is a bit headache. The recursion to 100 order was heavy. Doing it twice is more than complicated because of the computational speed.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate It is not clear what bootstrap/$\partial_\tau$ means. Do you want to find $\frac{d^n}{d\tau^n}\frac1{\eta(q(\tau))}$ or $\frac{d^n}{d\tau^n}\left[\frac d{d\tau}\frac1{\eta(q(\tau))}\right]$ or something else?

Comment: @TymaGaidash $\frac{d^n}{d\tau^n} \frac{1}{\eta(q(\tau))}$. The expression needed to be evaluated at given precision as fast as possible so it's different than just to obtain a symbolic expression. Currently I'm looking at the the Bell's polynomial and doing the recursion. But counting all functions, the actual formula is typically of the form $\frac{d^n}{d\tau^n} \frac{f(q(\tau))}{\eta(q(\tau)) }$ or, $Z(f(g(h(\tau))) ,\tau)$, so, without SDP, I needed to find a way to evaluate the derivatives fast.

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate If you look at formula $(20)$ in [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html), it may be that $\eta(q)$ is just an elliptic theta function. Powers of $\eta(x)$ are discussed [here](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/2100-20.pdf), so there should be a simplification of $\frac1{\eta(q(\tau))}$